# What are all the flags in pending intent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I know the concept of pending intent but the flags are confusing.

Even android documentation is very hard to understand

Can someone provide explanation of pending intent flags particularly `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` and `FLAG_NO_CREATE` with examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780579/4168607

Comment: This answer doesn't help. I just want examples and explanation of each flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PendingIntent`s are managed by the Android framework. When you call one of the `PendingIntent.getXXX()` methods, the framework tries to find an existing `PendingIntent` that matches the parameters you pass to the `getXXX()` method. If it finds a matching `PendingIntent` it will just return that to the caller. If it doesn't find a matching `PendingIntent` it will (usually) create a new `PendingIntent` and return that to the caller. You can alter this standard behaviour by using the flags:

- `FLAG_NO_CREATE` is used to get an existing `PendingIntent`. If a matching `PendingIntent` exists, it will be returned to the caller. If no matching `PendingIntent` exists, nothing happens. The framework will not create a new `PendingIntent` and the method returns `null` to the caller. You can use this method to determine if a specific `PendingIntent` exists. You can also use this method to get an existing `PendingIntent` so that you can cancel it.
- `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` is strange. According to the documentation, this flag should cause the `PendingIntent` to be deleted after it is used (sent). However, there are other side-effects of this flag. For example, if you create a `PendingIntent` using this flag, and then try to get this `PendingIntent` (or test the existence of it) by calling `PendingIntent.getXXX()` with `FLAG_NO_CREATE`, the framework will always return `null`. For this reason I never use it and I also recommend that it never be used.
- `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` is used to delete an existing `PendingIntent` and create a new one. The framework first tries to find a matching `PendingIntent`. If it finds one, it cancels (deletes) this `PendingIntent`. That means that any applications holding this `PendingIntent` will not be able to trigger (send) it. The framework then creates a new `PendingIntent` with the provided parameters and returns this to the caller.
- `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is used to update an existing `PendingIntent`. The framework first tries to find a matching `PendingIntent`. If it finds one, the "extras" in the existing `PendingIntent` are overwritten with the "extras" in the provided `Intent` parameter. If no matching `PendingIntent` is found, a new one is created with the provided parameters. The found (or newly created) `PendingIntent` is returned to the caller.

---

NOTE: See this answer for information on how the Android framework tries to find a "matching" `PendingIntent`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590084/769265

Comment: Will pending intent be running in the background?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `PendingIntent`s don't "run". They are sent. Depending on the `Intent` that is wrapped by the `PendingIntent`, this can result in starting an `Activity`, or a `BroadcastReceiver`, or a `Service`. Please explain what you are asking.

Comment: In this sentence `When you call one of the PendingIntent.getXXX() methods, the framework tries to find an existing PendingIntent that matches the parameters you pass to the getXXX() method`, you say that `it tries to find an existing intent`. My doubt was whether a pending intent will be running in the background? What exactly do you mean by that sentence?

Comment: In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778294/pending-intent-with-one-shot-flag/29780579#29780579) I have posted a comment, can you answer that?

Comment: I saw your comment but do not understand it either. You quote a passage that isn't in the question. Sorry.

Comment: I added a link to an answer that I wrote about how Android tried to find a matching `PendingIntent`. I still don't understand what you mean about "running in the background"

Comment: In the question asked by @greywolf82, after the code there is the sentence `If in the meantime someone asks for a new alarm, if the alarm exist I don't want to setup anything`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I see that now. I assume that he means that if he has already set an alarm, and it has not triggered yet, he doesn't want to set another one. He wants to just leave the original alarm. This is why he uses "FLAG_NO_CREATE". He is using this to test if the `PendingIntent` already exists. Unfortunately that doesn't work if he is using FLAG_ONE_SHOT which I note in my answer above.